# How to read a config.ts file at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a config.ts file as below:

```
import someConfig from './someConfigModel';

const config = {
  token: process.env.API_TOKEN,
  projectId: 'sample',
  buildId: process.env.BUILD_ID,
};

export default config as someConfig;
```

Is there a way at runtime to read this config in another module by passing the name of this file? Also I would like to see the config properties like `token` be auto-filled.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. How can one read a config *not* at runtime?

Comment: Sorry new to typescript. I have another .ts file that asks user for a config.ts at runtime. It then needs to get the data from the specified file.

Comment: Okay, makes sense so far. And what exactly happens when you start the application?

Comment: It asks the user to enter path of a config typescript file.

Comment: What is "it"? Enter where? Are you working in a terminal or in a file? Is this a design-time error (when writing the code) or a runtime error (when starting the app)? What exactly is the error? If there is no error, what do you expect to happen that does not happen (or happens in a different way)?

Comment: I was able to find a solution. See my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: 1) `someConfig` is a type (interfaces are also types), so it should have been named `SomeConfig` by convention, (with an uppercase `S`); that was the source of my confusion. 2) The syntax `export const config: SomeConfig = {...};` should be sufficient

Comment: On the reading side, it is `import { config } from './config`, or `const { config } = await import('./config)`, nothing more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated config file:

```
// config.ts
import SomeConfig from './someConfigModel';

export const config: SomeConfig = {
  token: process.env.API_TOKEN,
  projectId: 'sample',
  buildId: process.env.BUILD_ID,
};
```

Solution:

```
const module = await import('./config.ts');
const _config = module['config'] as someConfig;
```